# ServiceLocatorFactoryBean @transactional

Tags: spring, javabeans, factory, transactional

can someone please explain it to me, is it possible to forward existing opened transaction to a service that has been created with **ServiceLocatorFactoryBean** in Spring, and how does the factory manages transactions.

I have issues with a transaction rollback in the service that was created by the factory, in a way that if I throw checked exception in it, the transaction will be committed regardless the fact that the exception occurred.

My service is annotated with @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, rollbackFor = MyException.class), so it should use the existing transaction and it should rollback in case of the checked exception.

I assume that somehow, a new transaction is opened during creation of a new service, so although one transaction gets rollbacked, the other one gets committed independently.

Comment: Don't really have the time to test a proper answer, but I guess the beans created by your factory aren't being proxied by spring. You could look at suing something like `DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator` to create proxies so that the transaction annotations will be evaluated.

Comment: somewhere its  committed, share some code.